# Is a combined AC/Dehumidifer unit more efficient than separate units?

Tags: basement, air-conditioning, humidity

I've just moved into a "basement-ish" apartment; the actual ground level is about at my waist.  It's a bit mustier than I'd hoped, and not as cool as I'd like during these closing days of Summer.  I'm looking to pick up a small dehumidifier, and a small portable air conditioner, one to handle dampness in general; and the other to keep me cool.

In looking at my portable AC options, I see that there are a bunch of them that also function as dehumidifiers, on their own.  Does anyone know if they're decent and efficient at this task?  Should I stick to purchasing separate units, or can I get by with a two-in-one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, an AC unit is a dehumidifier by default -- so the two in one things are just advertising something that an AC unit already does.

Comment: Sure, but in the winter, it'll only be running the fan; it will be too cold for the thermostat to trigger the compressor/condenser.

Comment: The compressor has to run in order to dehumidify.  A dehumidifier is simply an air conditioner that doesn't keep the cold air separate from the hot air.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that a two-in-one will be as flexible as two separate units. Most ACs have a fixed relationship between the level of de-humidification and the level of cooling. There will likely be times when you want just de-humidification without cooling.

So if you can afford it, you will be more comfortable with two units.